# Problems getting email column to ignore no changes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem with the `email_customer` column.

In an insertion field of type `POST`, the excerpt below blocks the function of inserting an e-mail belonging to a customer in the `customers` table:

```
'POST' => [
    'email_customer' => ['required','max:50','email', Rule::unique('customers','email_customer')->ignore($this->id)],
],
```

Now in a `PATCH` form for validations. I want it to be possible to keep the value of `email_customer` without the `Unique` validation not triggering, because otherwise it blocks me from updating the email with one that already belongs to a customer in the customers table.

```
'PATCH' => [
    'email_customer' => ['required','max:50','email', Rule::unique('customers','email_customer')->ignore($this->id)],
],
```

`CustomerRequest.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class CustomerRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return match ($this->method()) {
            'POST' => [
                'email_customer' => ['required','max:50','email', Rule::unique('customers','email_customer')->ignore($this->id)],
            ],
            'PATCH' => [
                'email_customer' => ['required','max:50','email', Rule::unique('customers','email_customer')->ignore($this->id)],
            ],
        };
    } 
}
```

How i fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `costumers != customers` ... ideally for `POST` you would not be excluding anything from the unique restriction since it should be trying to insert a new record, only the `PATCH` (update) should need to exclude an id from the unique check ... can you expand on what the result currently is with what you have for the POST and PATCH routes?

Comment: in POST, block the insertion of emails that already belong to a record, while the PATCH must block the updating of the value of the email field to one that already exists (the same as in POST) and that must ignore the field if there is no update , for example, even if I don't change anything in the ```email_customers``` form, it still triggers the uniqueness validation.

Comment: Ive achieved this by doing a query with a where not. passed through a method and added a in: '. $this->method($id).' then you can get any of the customer ids where not that one id.

Comment: @kray can show me this in code?